# Is there a way to place all parts of a connector at once in Altium?

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a part with 50 pins and currently it only allows me to place one pin at a time. Is there a way to do that quicker? Currently I have to place one pin and then right click it to change it to part 5/50 and so on. [image: Picture of pins]

Comment: Redraw a new symbol that has all 50 pins in one block.

Answer (score 0):

You need a component--it will have your schematic symbol and your PCB footprint, and sometimes a 3D model.  Sites like [this](https://www.pcb-3d.com/membership_type/free/) offer some for free, and many manufacturers will provide component models.  If not, you can create it yourself; it's basically the same as what you're doing now, but if you use the part again you'll already have it.